# copiar de la hoja inicial

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Estoy queriendo copiar datos de una celda a otra hoja del mismo documento con Google Script.

Pero en lugar de copiar de una hoja específica:

```
spreadsheet.getRange('\'1\'!B2:F2').copyTo
```

Quiero copiar de la hoja que inicia la macro. En **vba** usaba:

```
HojaIni = ActiveSheet.Name
```

Pero no funciona en **Google Sheets**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Claro que lo que usabas en VBA no funciona con las hojas de cálculo de Google ya que estas usan otra cosa, Google Apps Script.

Para obtener la hoja actual puedes usar:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
```

Si por inicial te refieres a la primer hoja usa

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];
```

Referencias

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets

Comment: Hola Ruben, gracias por la respuesta. Lo de VBA lo ponía de referencia para ver si a alguien le había sucedido. En mi caso necesito volver siempre a la misma hoja para ejecutar un nuevo comando dentro de una misma macro. Por tanto no me sirve activesheet. me serviría algo de tipo "hoja previa". Voy a revisar la referencia que pasaste para ver si encuentro algo allí. Gracias!!

Comment: ¿Te refieres a usar VBA en Google Apps Script? Por lo que he visto si hay otros que lo han intentado con los mismos resultados, no les funciona :)

Comment: En relación a lo que estás buscando en específico, te sugiero publicar una nueva pregunta pues ya has recibido lo que considero que es una buena respuesta para la pregunta planteada, considerando que el código de VBA incluido usa `ActiveSheet`. Por cierto, si no lo has hecho aún por favor lee [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien responde mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta! Lo seguiremos intentando